# What is wrong with my simple math equation

Tags: javascript, html, math

I am trying to create a simple calculator that will return the amount of sales tax plus the amount after tax. If I input $80 and the sales tax is 7.5% I should get back an amount of $86 but instead I am getting $806 returned to me. I am unsure why.

```
    //calculation
    var total = (itemCost + (itemCost * salesTax/100));


    total = Math.round(total)
```

Comment: `itemCost` and `salesTax` are strings.

Answer (score 2):

you need `var total = (parseInt(itemCost) + (parseInt(itemCost) * salesTax/100));`

Comment: What does parseInt do?

Comment: The parseInt() function parses a string and returns an integer, as demonstrated by [JavaScript parseInt() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp). You need to convert string to integer before performing calculation.

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that when you retrieve the value, it is a string. Parse it as a number value by doing:

```
var salesTax = Number(document.getElementById("salesTax").value);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are getting the values of the text fields you have strings. Javascript does a lot of type inferring, that's why it almost works. Your expression gets translated to:

(String)"80" + ((String)"80"*(int)0.075)

(String)"80" + (int)6

And now the String operator+(String, Any) is called which is defined as string concatenation. Therefore you end up with "80" + "6" => "806".

If you for example would write:
"80" * "1" + "80" * "7.5"/"100" you would indeed get the expected result of 86.

But to be sure everything works as expected you should indeed parse the values from a string value to a number value (with parseInt resp. parseFloat).